# Hibernate Criteria for Join Table

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

Help me Hibernate Guru..
i have 2 relationship class, let's call class A and B

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A extends Serializable{

      @Id
      @Column(name="a_id")
      private int id;
      @Column(name="a_name")
      private String name;

     /*
      *.....Setter and Getter
      */
}



@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B extends Serializable{

      @Id
      @Column(name="b_id")
      private int id;
      @ManyToMany(
          fetch= FetchType.EAGER,
          targetEntity=package.A.class,
          cascade={CascadeType.ALL}
      )
      @JoinTable(
          name="B_A",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="b_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="a_id")
      )
      @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
      private List<A> list;

     /*
      *.....Setter and Getter
      */
}
```

Hibernate will generate 3 Table A, B, and B_A. with table B_A have 2 foreign key, one foreign key for primary key table A and one again foreign key for primary key table B,

i want select data from table A, like query :

```
select * from A a inner join B_A ba on ba.a_id = a.id inner join B b on b.b_id = ba.b_id where b.id in(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

so how Criteria code i have to create???? and for expected list result List i want to use Transformer.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
criteria.createCriteria(A.class)
.createCriteria("id", "join_between_a_b")
.add(Restrictions.eq("some_field_of_A", someValue));
```

Remember, A and B have to have `id` as their identifiers in order to make them join.
By `some_field_of_A` I mean anything you like in class A, like `name` for example. You can have restriction over any properties of these classes.